# Jquery slidetoggle Show Hide One div at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, show-hide, slidetoggle

I am having an issue to create a Jquery toggle that opens one `div` at a time.

I want that only one content shows up when i click on the `div` (`show`). Here, they both open at the same time.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $content = $(".content").hide();
        $(".toggle").on("click", function(e){
            $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
            $content.slideToggle();
        });
});
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z7F75/590/)

Also:  How can you add the option so that the open div hide once you open a new one but also give you the option to hide the one that is currently open even if you don't open a new `div` by clicking on the `"hide"` text)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this several ways. With your current html markup you could use [jQuery's Next Function](https://api.jquery.com/next/).

```
$(".toggle").on("click", function(e){
    $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

Or you could wrap your toggle and content in a div and use the [parent](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) and [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) functions.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="toggle"></div>
    <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(".toggle").on("click", function(e){
    $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
    $(this).parent().find('.content').slideToggle();
});
```

If you want all other `.content` to `slideUp` when you toggle one of them, just select all `.content` divs and use [jQuery's Not Function](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to exclude the div you just toggled.

```
$(".toggle").on("click", function(e){
    var target = $(this).parent().find('.content');
    $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
    target.slideToggle();
    $('.content').not( target ).slideUp();
});
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much.It works great.   What about adding the option to close a div automatically once you open a new one ? What do i need to put in the code for that ? Thank you.

Comment: And how would you have the ' toggle ' name to change  and get back to " show ". because with this code if content is open and toggle is ' hide ', if i click on another toggle, content will slideup but the toggle name ' hide ' will remain.  thank you very much. You've been really helpful.

Comment: Use the `not` function. Like this `$('.toggle').not( $(this) ).removeClass('expanded');`. That will remove the expanded class from all `.toggle` elements that are not the one clicked on.